# Can I convert browser generated image blob to image file for upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, canvas, meteor, meteor-slingshot

I'm using fabric.js to dynamically create textures in Threes.js, and I need to save the textures to AWS. I'm using meteor-slingshot, which normally takes images passed in through a *file selector* input. Here's the uploader:

```
var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");

uploader.send(document.getElementById('input').files[0], function (error, downloadUrl) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading', uploader.xhr.response);
    alert (error);
  }
  else {
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$push: {"profile.files":downloadUrl}});
  }
});
```

**Uploading works fine from the drive ...** but I'm generating my files in the browser, not getting them from the drive. Instead, they are generated from a canvas element with the following method:

```
    generateTex: function(){
        var canvTex         = document.getElementById('texture-generator');
        var canvImg         = canvTex.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        var imageNew        = document.createElement( 'img' );
        imageNew.src        = canvImg;

    }
```

**This works great as well**. If I console.log the imageNew, I get my lovely image with base 64 encoding:

```
 <img src=​"data:​image/​jpeg;​base64,/​9j/​
4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgID 
//....carries on to 15k or so characters
```

If I `console.log` a file object added from the drive via filepicker ( **not generated from a canvas** ), I can see what the file object *should* look like:

```
file{
  lastModified: 1384216556000
  lastModifiedDate: Mon Nov 11 2013 16:35:56 GMT-0800 (PST)
  name: "filename.png"
  size: 3034
  type: "image/png"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
  __proto__: File
}
```

But I can't create a file from the blob for upload, because there is no place in the file object to add the actual data.

To sum up I can:

1. Generate an image blob and display it in a dom element
2. Upload files from the drive using meteor-slingshot
3. inspect the existing file object

But I don't know how to convert the blob into a named file, so I can pass it to the uploader.

I don't want to download the image, (there are answers for that), I want to upload it. There is a "chrome only" [way to do this with the filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) but I need something cross browser (and eventually cross platform). If someone could help me with this, I would have uncontainable joy.

Comment: just found this: http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/qnYk4/3/ and info about saveAs() and fileSaver.js ... that might do the trick...I'll leave it open for a bit to see if anyone has additional suggestions.

Comment: actually, that's all for downloading... :(

Comment: did you add the required settings to your meteor settings? https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot#aws-s3

Comment: Yes, I didn't post all the code for the meteor-slingshot, because the upload is actually working fine (as long as I'm adding a file from my own computer).  I just don't know how to turn a blob from a generated image into an uploadable file. Seems like it should be easy!

Comment: Could it be linked to the fact that browsers actually restrict file upload to files selected after a user interaction? I remember having the problem for base64 encoded files coming from a webview, I ended up sending the base64 through post to an API and do the upload server side. I don't know if it would change something to generate the image from base64 _after_ an action from the user

Comment: maybe this could help : https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/issues/114

Comment: Definitely helpful info! The OP of the issue didn't seem to get it resolved though, and the two stack overflow posts were either from the server or from phonegap ... I'll read them again tomorrow and see if I can find something there. Good searching, I thought I had seen everything in their issues!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slingshot supports blobs just as well as files: https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/issues/22

So when you have a canvas object called `canvTex` and a `Slingshot.Upload` instance called `uploader`, then uploading the canvas image is as easy as:

```
canvTex.toBlob(function (blob) {
  uploader.send(blob, function (error, downloadUrl) {
    //...
  });
});
```

Because blobs have no names, you must take that into account when defining your directive. Do not attempt to generate a key based on the name of the file.

Comment: That's great, can't wait to try that out. From what I read in that issue, I can assign a name to the blob to name the file. That's perfect!